# Is the homogenous ideal of a complete intersection always radical?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let's say we have a complete intersection Z in $\mathbb{P}^2$ defined by two curves $f_1,f_2$ that meet transversely in the maximum number of points allowed by Bezout's theorem. Is the ideal (f_1,f_2) radical? I think it has to be, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but hypersurfaces are trivially complete intersections, and the ideal of a hypersurface $X$ is radical iff $X$ is reduced. For something more interesting, just take a conic and a tangent line in $\mathbb P^2$, e.g. $zy - x^2=0$ and $y=0$. The homogeneous ideal of the intersection is $\langle x^2, y \rangle$ which has radical $\langle x,y\rangle$.

Comment: If this isn't true then I am confused. Lets say I have two curves $f_1$ and $f_2$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ that meet transversely at the maximum number of distinct points allowed by Bezout's theorem. How can I compute the hilbert function of $Z(f_1, f_2)$ if $I(Z(f_1,f_2)) \neq (f_1,f_2)$?  Is it the maximal number of intersections that makes this true?